# In what location should I install the composer

Tags: magento-2.1

I have Linux server and my magento folder is located in:

```
/home/b2b/domains/mydomains.com/public_html/<magento here>
```

I have found how to install composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

But where I should run above command ? In root server folder after open putty or first go to magento folder:

```
cd /home/b2b/domains/mydomains.com/public_html/
```

and then run ?

Comment: root location install composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install composer itself does not has a relation to `Magento` location, you can install it at the root of the server, or you can contact with server technical support to install it. after that you can install Magento using composer at `public_html`.

Comment: thanks. I have installed composer. I have last question. Now I have to install language pack so I have to run command: composer require mageplaza/magento-2-polish-language-pack:dev-master. Also this command should I run on root on my server ?

Comment: No, at the root of project.